# Querying Bigtable prefix from Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

Using BigQuery's Bigtable external data source, I'd like to find rowkeys in Bigtable that start with a certain value. This is a very fast operation in `cbt` or other Bigtable-native tools, but seems slow in BigQuery.

```sql
SELECT rowkey from blah.blah where rowkey LIKE '123%' group by rowkey
```

It seems to be processing a lot of data, perhaps even the whole Bigtable table, to find results, rather than using Bigtable's native prefix operation which is very fast.

Am I using the most efficient query in BigQuery for this?

Comment: Related question: Are you using #standardSQL? That might have fixed everything

Comment: It does fix everything! Processes far less data with far faster query result. Thank you.

Comment: ^ This should probably be the answer!

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I'm able to query rowkey with #standardSQL but can't figure out how to query cell values in Bigtable - is there a good example? `SELECT
  default.column.cell.value` works in legacy SQL but returns a `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword DEFAULT` in #standardSQL

Comment: SELECT \`default.column.cell.value\` w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```sql
WHERE rowkey LIKE '123%'
```

try:

```sql
WHERE rowkey > '123'
```

The connector between BigQuery and Bigtable could be smarter about this (internal discussion started), but in the meantime this should fix the issue.

Comment: I still experience BQ scanning whole Bigtable, using all approaches, (like or >, in both standard and legacy SQL). Is there a reason why this could be failing?

Comment: Can confirm that this approach is working. For a table with 300k rows the difference is 10 minutes vs 2 seconds execution time. Thank you for this answer!